# Regex formula to extract civic numbers

Tags: regex, ssis

I have this Regex formula to extract Civic number from a list of addresses using SSIS and Script component.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        //Replace each \ with \\ so that C# doesn't treat \ as escape character
        //Pattern: Start of string, any integers, 0 or 1 letter, end of word
        string sPattern = "^[0-9]+([A-Za-z]\\b)?";
        string sString = Row.ADDRESS ?? ""; //Coalesce to empty string if NULL

        //Find any matches of the pattern in the string
        Match match = Regex.Match(sString, sPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //If a match is found
        if (match.Success)
            //Return the first match into the new
            //HouseNumber field
            Row.CivicNumber = match.Groups[0].Value;
        else
            //If not found, leave the HouseNumber blank
            Row.CivicNumber = "";
    }

}
```

In works well for addresses like

- 49b Main street : which return me in the column "CivicNumber" -> 49b

I do have some in this format :

- 49b/15 Main street:  i would like it returns me in the column "CivicNumber" -> 49b/15

How i can modify my Regex formula to return my desired results?

Comment: This code is copied verbatim from the example here: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/ - why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string sPattern = "^[0-9]+[A-Za-z]?\\b(/[0-9]+)?";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about anything starting with a number up until a space? For example:

```
\d\S+
```

[image]

If the address/line must start with a number, then you can use the anchor as you have above in your question:

```
^\d\S+
```

Answer (score 1):

***Do not have enough reputation to comment***

So from your two examples can I assume that the substring before the first space is your civic number?
If yes, then you can split the word by space characters and get the first substring from the string array.

```
String address = "49b/15 Main Street";
String[] addressArr = address.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(addressArr[0]);
```